# Post link with unusual characters in hash

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

I would like to include a link in an answer to the following URL:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Decimal Digit Character: \d

Note that the hash is supposed to go all the way to the end of the line, including the spaces, colon, and backslash. How on earth do I accomplish that? URLEncoding the hash doesn't work. Using an html anchor tag doesn't work (it URLEncodes the hash, too).

Here's an example attempt:

[\d Regex character class in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Decimal Digit Character: \d)

I also tried %20 in place of the spaces, and +, but none of them navigate to the correct section.

Comment: %20 seems to work for me: [\d Regex character class in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Decimal%20Digit%20Character:%20\d). Though it looks like the link should actually be `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#DigitCharacter`.

Comment: @MikeM. You beat me by 4 seconds... I found out the same things as you, sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was fast.

The answer is: use `%20` in place of spaces, as [spaces are not valid in this part of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849800/57611). Also `/` needs to be encoded as `%5d`.

I figured out that when navigating using the links on the right side of the linked page, the hash that is placed in the URL is part of some javascript page navigation and doesn't actually refer to an id within the page, so nothing I could have done to the above hash value would have made it work. There IS a usable id in the page, though, so hash `#DigitCharacter` will work for my link. Using percent hex encoding *should* theoretically have worked, if the page was actually "listening" to the hash value, which it isn't.

Example link that *should* work, and can be put into a manual link using markdown:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Decimal%20Digit%20Character:%20%5cd

I'm not deleting my question because it might help someone else.